# How to produce a CSV file of certain elements of a complex JSON object using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, csv

The following JSON object is the current output of some JavaScript behind a web form. I would like to take the coordinates from all occurrences of entry and exit, in all occurrences of tracks and intersections, and output the data into a CSV file.

I don't want to download the JSON file, run it through a local program, and get the CSV, so a separate Python program may not be the answer. Ideally, the JavaScript would just output the CSV.

```
[
    {"info": 
        {"tracks": 
            [{"entry": {
                 "y": 773,
                 "x": 242,
                 "z": 28
             },
              "exit": {
                 "y": 545,
                 "x": 432,
                 "z": 28},
              "colorIndex": 4,
              "n_particles": -1},
            {"entry": {
                 "y": 244,
                 "x": 43,
                 "z": 28},
              "exit": {
                 "y": 178,
                 "x": 270,
                 "z": 28},
              "colorIndex": 5,
              "n_particles": -1}
              ],...
```

I have been working off the following code
http://jsfiddle.net/hybrid13i/JXrwM/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=JXrwM
but can only yield a CSV of the elements of the same "level" as "info".

Any guidance is much appreciated. Thanks.

Sam

Comment: what is the desired outcome? I mean: what should it look like?

Comment: Ultimately, I am aiming for a spreadsheet with 2 columns, "Tracks" and "Intersections", each of which has 3 sub-columns, "x", "y" and "z", with the rows alternating between entry and exit coordinates. However, any form in which I can easily access the data would be fine, and I can tinker later.

Comment: what about "colorIndex" & "n_particles" ?

Comment: I don't need to include those in the CSV file.

Comment: I'm curious though, why CSV? There are many ways to delimit data. Is it just to compress the file-size of the JSON?

Comment: I need to allow people to easily access and run calculations with the data (such as averaging the z coordinates), and thought CSV would be most convenient, thanks to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, some of the "columns" are omitted in the example, so:

You can try this tool to convert JSON to CSV: https://json-csv.com/

Then, look at the outcome, and write your JavaScript to delimit accordingly.

### Edit:

Once you've converted the data and you need to know how to write a JavaScript algorithm to achieve that, update the question accordingly as it will be clear what the delimiting characters should be. This answer will then be updated accordingly, but it is still useful to others whom are looking for a popular way to convert JSON to CSV and see what could be expected in the results.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. My error was in navigating the JSON after I had parsed it. Dots for objects and square brackets for arrays! 

    parsedResults[0].info.tracks[0].entry

takes me to the entry coordinates as one object. The example shown here http://halistechnology.com/2015/05/28/use-javascript-to-export-your-data-as-csv/ then helped me to form a CSV.